# Why is my json file converting to just a blank CSV?

Tags: json, csv, python-3.7

I'm trying to convert my JSON file to CSV but it's not working. There's no error but it's just a blank CSV. Here's my code.

```
#CONVERT JSON TO CSV FILE
infile = open('leads.json','r')
outfile = open('leads2.csv','w')

writer = csv.writer(outfile)

for row in json.loads(infile.read()):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in,

```
for row in json.loads(infile.read()):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

`writerow` takes an array, while `row` is not an array.

When using `for` to iterate through a dict ( that json.loads gives you), `row` gives you one key at a time.